# GoLang query for MySQL appending to a JSON field

Tags: mysql, json, go

I'm trying to write a query that would append my JSON variable("data") to a JSON field in my database. I have a table called cart with three fields inside: `id type int`, `status type varchar` and `items type json`. So basically I'm trying to write a query where it would find my cart by the id and it would add an item to the end of my `item field` so far what I have is this:

```
query, err := db.Exec("UPDATE cart SET items = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(@items, '$', 'data') where id = 1")
```

I know this is not enough. How can I add my variable instead of 'data' to this query? Could anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be a parameterized update:

```
db.Exec("UPDATE cart SET items = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(@items, '$', ?) where id = ?", data, 1)
```